# How to set the "MAIL FROM" header for an email?

Tags: email, go, sparkpost, gomail

In the SparkPost (an email sending provider) documentation for setting "bounce domains" it says

> specified in the [...] mail from header in the SMTP payload

https://www.sparkpost.com/docs/tech-resources/custom-bounce-domain/

But when I set the "MAIL FROM" header I get a response from their server stating

> 550 5.6.0 Invalid header found (see RFC2822 section 3.6)

I'm using the plugin `gomail "gopkg.in/gomail.v2"`

What does setting the "MAIL FROM" header actually mean? How do I set it?

Comment: `MAIL FROM` is an SMTP command, not a header.  It looks like the package gets  the command argument from the `from` argument to the [Sender.Send](https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/gomail.v2#Sender.Send) method (this is a guess based on how other packages work, this is the first time that I've looked at the gomail package).

Comment: I agree with CeriseLimón. The first argument of [Sender.Send](https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/gomail.v2#Send) is used for the `MAIL FROM` SMTP command according to the source code.

Comment: Alright interesting, well apparently it's possible set a different "MAIL FROM" than the From in the header according to SparkPost, I'm dealing with their support to see what they actually want me to send to them

Answer (score 0):

So it's not a header in the email, maybe their documentation says that incorrectly.

But it's one of the commands sent to the SMTP server when sending the email to the server. This is all handled in `gomail`, which uses the `net/smtp` package's `Mail()` function.

Instead of using

```golang
return dialer.DialAndSend(m)
```

you can call the `Send()` function directly on the message, and pass to it a different address.

```golang
s, err := dialer.Dial()
if err != nil {
    return err
}
defer s.Close()

m := gomail.NewMessage()
mailFrom := "bounces@bounce.example.com"
to := []string{"receiver@example.com"}

return s.Send(mailFrom, to, m)
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I got the same error:

```
550 5.6.0 Invalid header found (see RFC2822 section 3.6)
```

After a bit of trial and error, I found that it was not an invalid header, but it was because the `Subject:` header was missing. Adding a subject solved the problem.